# Need a resource for pairing cities to coordinates

Tags: dictionary, coordinate

I have a list of cities (and some other locations) around the world, formatted like this:

```
America/Antigua  
America/Anguilla  
Europe/Tirane  
Asia/Yerevan  
America/Curacao  
Africa/Luanda  
Antarctica/McMurdo
```

And I need to get their corresponding coordinates formatted like this:

```
Europe/Stockholm 59.21N 18.04W
```

Since I have a rather large list (around 1k posts) I would like to be able to automate the retrieval of these coordinates. Does there exist a free resource (preferably downloadable, not search-only) from which it's easy to extract this data?

The alternatives I can think of at the moment are google maps (which would require an api key, if I understand it correctly), or Wikipedia (which doesn't have that data easily available, and is not optimized for that kind of searches). And both of these are online-only, which is sub-optimal for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/)

I am sure you can query that service for free but I dont know if that data can be downloadable

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. You can download a dump of their database from here: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/ From a quick look, it seems that all locations I'm looking for are in the cities1000.zip package.

Comment: Glad to help. Dont forget to mark the question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.realestate3d.com/gps/world-latlong.htm